# Could not find library.aar (com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.30)

Tags: android

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not find library.aar (com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.30).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/anjlab/android/iab/v3/library/1.0.30/library-1.0.30.aar

How can I resolve?

Answer (score 2):

You may follow below listed steps.Enjoy!

1) Open your app's build.gradle file.
2) change the dependent library identifier to 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'
3) You just need to remove the @aar stuff.